# Eclipse is not loading?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse was working fine just a day ago. But today, when I click the eclipse icon, it only loads the splash screen and nothing else thereafter, I even don't get to see the splash screen which contains that 'green loading sign' at the bottom, and -- while monitoring the `eclipse.exe` in Windows Task Manager(just after starting eclipse) -- I saw that even after the splash screen went off the screen, the `eclipse.exe` process went with it, after a few seconds. Keep in mind that I did NOT see any warning or error messages because, (I'm assuming, that the loading haven't gone to a point where it is capable of sending any error message)

Hence, I tried reinstalling eclipse, by copying from INSIDE the .zip directory of the installation folder and pasting it inside the eclipse program directory. But the exact same problem persists. So, now I'm currently downloading the latest version of eclipse to retry again.

Any other Advice?

#### UPDATE

It turned out that the hard drive containing the workspace was partially corrupted, hence I cleaned it; following that, the workspace data was still accessible. (Though usually I still keep a backup on hand.)

Comment: Have you tried 'eclipse.exe -clean'?

Comment: Have you updated anything, or changed anything in the past day?

Comment: I've tried the clean command when starting eclipse from 'Run'. But the same problem persists

Comment: Have you looked at the logfile in the workspace's .metadata directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the hard drive containing the workspace was partially corrupted, hence I cleaned it; following that, the workspace data was still accessible. (Though usually I still keep a backup on hand.)

Answer (score 3):

just delete the .metadata folder from workspace and reload the eclipse. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping you have the links to the update sites for your installed plugins, my advice is to download eclipse, download your already installed plugins from their update site's and then open the new eclipse and set the workspace to your actual workspace. More far than that is to trash your time... trust me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something went wrong with Java. Try re-installing Java run-time.

Answer (score 0):

It also can mean a problem with the eclipse.ini file (like an extra space at the end of the line), or a problem with the JVM path (since the splash screen is displayed by the eclipse.exe, before loading all the eclipse Java classes).

Check that eclipse.ini file and consider my [**ini file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) as a good optimization source.

Answer (score 0):

If your workspace has been corrupted your safest approach is to create a new one.

I would actually strongly suggest that you reinstall everything that might have been corrupted, to avoid as much strangeness as possible.  This includes the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out both 
(1)E:\eclipse-standard-luna-RC3-win32\eclipse -clean in run
(2)deleting .metadata folder from workspace

I do not which one worked for me.Thanks...